# What does "Connected via Camera" mean?

Tags: wi-fi, android-10

I have a Motorola G7 Plus (UK model) connected to my home wifi router. When I choose Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi, I see that under the name of my router, it says "Connected via Camera". What does this mean? (I don't actually have a camera, other than the one in my phone.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Connected via Camera" means that the WiFi access point was added by scanning [a QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Joining_a_Wi%E2%80%91Fi_network) using the Camera app.**

From [`frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libs/WifiTrackerLib/res/values/strings.xml`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libs/WifiTrackerLib/res/values/strings.xml;l=99?q=%22Connected%20via%22&start=51) file:

> ```
> <!-- Status message of Wi-Fi when it is connected by a app (via suggestion or network request). [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
> <string name="wifitrackerlib_connected_via_app">Connected via <xliff:g id="name" example="Wifi App">%1$s</xliff:g></string>
> ```

which is used inside the [`getConnectedDescription()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/opt/net/wifi/libs/WifiTrackerLib/src/com/android/wifitrackerlib/Utils.java;l=229?q=%22Connected%20via%22&start=11) function to show additional info of the WiFi connection, otherwise only showing "Connected".

---

Additional reference: [motorola - Can't delete / forget wifi added with QR](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/moto-g8-power/Can-t-delete-forget-wifi-added-with-QR/m-p/5138463).